# Use mysql over tcp connection

Tags: mysql, sockets, tcp

I have a mysql database, setup with docker.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: foo
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

I want to access this mysql socket via `TCP`, login into my db and execute a simple mysql command.

I'm trying to implement this in `rust` but a solution for any other programmlanguage will fit

```
 let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:3306").expect("Could not connect");

 let mut cmd = "CREATE TABLE foo.payment (
                         customer_id int not null,
                         amount int not null,
                         account_name text
                     )".as_bytes();
 let foo = stream.write(cmd).expect("Could not write to tcp socket");
```

I have not much knowledge with TCP and sockets - but I want to learn more about it.

My question:

How can I write some kind of mysql driver using TCP ? I do not want to use an existing library for stuff like this, since I want to get a better understanding

1. Login into my mysql db
2. Execute a query

Comment: Read the MySQL documentation if it contains information about the protocol, read libmysql sources... It’s not a trivial task.

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to use an existing MySQL client library.

Comment: Got any solutions? I am also learning rust to get a low-level understanding of computers and networks.